# How to configure Apache Server to change the context path

Tags: java, apache

I have the login url : `Aslam:20002/MxPortalSimulator/jsp/login.jsp`

Once I login the url will change, as in JSP we are using `contextPath` `action="contextPath/login"`, the context path is changing the URL to this one  : Aslam:20002/MxPortalSimulator/login

In httpd-ssl-conf i have proxypass url as `/` `Aslam:20002/MxPortalSimulator/jsp/login.jsp`

Once I login the apache is giving context as - `MxPortalSimulator/jsp/login.jsp` 
and the Jsp is directing the url as

```
Aslam:20002/MxPortalSimulator/jsp/login.jsp/MxPortalSimulator/login
```

Instead we want only `Aslam:20002/MxPortalSimulator/login`

How to configure it Can somebody please help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
action="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login"
```

Note : Added a forward slash `/` in front. This will make it as an absolute path from the context and will not be relative from the current path

Comment: Thanks Octopus, are you telling this in JSP page.